# Webpage won't load due to "Cannot connect to server error"

Tags: android, connection

I have the following activity that will connect to a webpage.

The activity works but it can never connect to a webpage regardless of what website it is, I keep getting the same message.

Can anyone see anything wrong with the code?

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {
     private WebView mWebview ; // Creates a webview

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mWebview  = new WebView(this);

            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//Enables javascript 

            final Activity activity = this;

            mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {//Starts the web browser
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");//Sets what website will be opened.
            setContentView(mWebview );//Displays the website,

        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission in Android Manifest file & see.

Comment: I knew it'd just be something so small! Thanks a lot :)